# How to detect the process (and mysql query) that makes high load on server?

Tags: mysql, high-load

From time to time load on my server (centos 4)jumps to 15 or more. I need to discover what process causes this high load on server.
It there any script which can handle this for me ?
I think its caused by mysql so even to discover the sql query would be great help.

Answer (score 6):

High server load typically caused by disk I/O. There are some ways to identify which process is waiting for disk I/O:

- `iotop`
- `top -b -i -n 10`
- `atop` and press `D`
- `htop` -> `F2` to add 2 columns `IO_RBYTES` and `IO_WBYTES`, then `F6` to sort
- ...

You should especially pay attention to the processes in `D` state (uninterruptible sleep):

```
watch "ps -eo pid,user,state,command | awk '\$3 == /D/ { print \$0 }'"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST\G
```

look for something with a long runtime.

then EXPLAIN  to see if it's making full table scans, generating temp tables, etc.

Otherwise, you can use something like the free version of Jet ( http://www.jetprofiler.com/ )

Garrett

Comment: Another tool to look at is Innotop (http://code.google.com/p/innotop/) a top clone for MySQL. Also check out the Percona Toolkit (http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit/)

Answer (score 0):

If it is the case that mysql is the cause of the high load, then Mysql supports a `slow_query_log` argument, and once enabled it will log any particularly slow queries to a file;
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html

> The slow query log consists of SQL statements that took more than long_query_time seconds to execute and required at least min_examined_row_limit rows to be examined. The minimum and default values of long_query_time are 0 and 10, respectively.